# How to copy IIS 7.0 website to local computer running IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, iis

i want to copy contents, code, build files and configuration files from a IIS(7.0) server which is running a live file and copy everything 
to another machine which got IIS 8 installed. 
the destination computer has other web sites installed, so i dont want to disturb configuration for those sites.
do i first copy the code from the source and create a folder on destination and copy the files there and than follow with the configuration settings?

Comment: If its hosted on a server look for C:\inetpub\wwwroot the folder of your website will be there copy the whole folder and save folder on the another machine in wwwroot folder

Answer (score 1):

Probably meant for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)...but here goes..

1. Review/inventory current application. e.g.

   - "config files" for any explicit settings that may have to do with `paths`, connections (db), certificates (ssl), and/or expected `depedencies` (assemblies, framework version/s, other web applications, etc.)
   - hopefully the application is documented and/or original developers are handy to assist in this inventory process
   - the point is to first "know" what you're moving before doing anything, this would be the most important step..the rest is more or less config....
2. create folder in target machine

   - doesn't have to be in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, but you'll have to modify `permissions` as necessary.

     - also if there's an existing app in `wwwroot`, possible headaches can arise with settings inheritance
3. copy files from source -> target
4. `IIS Manager` -> set up the new "web site"/"Application" as necessary (`AppPool`, etc.)
5. Test, test, test
6. Fallback plan (if all goes to hell, need to "revert")
7. Applicable network stuff - `DNS`, etc. (the moment of truth)
8. Coffee. Lots. Pray you don't have to go to #6 :)

Hth...